# Making cocoa app respond to automator actions

Tags: cocoa, automator

I would like to make my app respond to automator actions, similar to the way iPhoto has several actions associated with it (import photos, find iphoto items, new iPhoto album etc.).

I can make the actions, but do not know how to make my app respond to any of them (except the open files actions where I use: `- (void) application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames)`.

I can't find any docs or example code. Anything would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I also found some useful example code here:   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScriptingProperties/Listings/scriptLog_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004240-scriptLog_h-DontLinkElementID_9

And:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScriptingObjects/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

**[Introduction to Automator Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Automator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001674-SW1)**

That document should get you started...

Comment: The guide talks about how to implement actions. It is however remarkably quiet on the topic of *integrating them with the application*. The best I could find was using a combination of scripting support in the app and AppleScript action to use it -- kind of messy solution if you ask me.